# Python geneticalgorithm2 bounds with stepsize

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I'm using the geneticalgorithm2 module for minimization. I use mixed variables and my code is similar to the example given by them:

```
import numpy as np
from geneticalgorithm2 import geneticalgorithm2 as ga

def f(X):
    return np.sum(X)
    
varbound = [[0.5,1.5],[0,100],[0,1]]
vartype = ('real', 'int', 'int')
model = ga(function=f, dimension=3, variable_type=vartype, variable_boundaries=varbound)

model.run()
```

varbound shows the bounds of the variables and the tool will minimize between those values as expected. My question is: is it possible to choose the stepsize?

For example: the code will look between 0 and 100 for integers, but what can I do to make it look for tens only? So 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 and 100.
And what about a stepsize of 0.001 for the first variable (between 0.5 and 1.5).

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: I cannot find anything about this in the documentation. The only thing that can get close to this is using constraints, which is shown in the documentation. I have to use an if-statement then to filter out the iterations I don't want to have, but this is not the most efficient way.